# Comparison of two dna sequences in C

Tags: c

I would like to compare two dna sequences in C. How can i compare two strings and gets the difference?

Let's say:

seq_a:

`GATCAACGCAAAGGACTAAGCACTGCTGCCAAA`

and

seq_b:

`GATCAACGCAAAGGACTAAGCACTGCTGCCTGC`

result: TGC or `GATCAACGCAAAGGACTAAGCACTGCTGCC***`

Comment: One approach is by writing a code.

Comment: Show us an example. BTW what is a _codon_ ? Most of the people on SO are not biologists.

Comment: Copy of this question 2.5 years ago? http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/917878-comparison-two-dna-sequences

Comment: I think the typical approach is to use [BLAST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAST) or [BLAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAT_(bioinformatics)). A lot of work has been done to find very fast ways to compare DNA sequences, and writing your own code to do it (especially if you're asking *us* how) is surely the wrong approach.

Comment: @Caleb: he edited his question. No need of BLAST or BLAT, he wants hardly more than a simple string comparision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard-code the traversal of two strings in a while loop. If they're the same, output either string1[i] or string2[i]. If they're different, write a star.

Comment: Dear prkist, 

I'd like thank you so much for the answer. I would love to see a sample code about comparison of two strings in a while loop.

Comment: @careem: we'd love to see you try to do your own work.  When you run into problems and you've spent some time sorting them out, then you could think about coming back and asking for more help.